# How to run a workflow after another only on release?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have github workflow like this:

```yaml
name: publish

on:
  release:
    types: [published]
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [test]
    types: [completed]

jobs:
  on-success:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    steps:
      - run: echo 'The test workflow passed'
     

  on-failure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'failure' }}
    steps:
      - run: echo 'The test workflow failed'
```

I want to run `publish` workflow on releases and after `test` is passed. But it runs on every push to `main` after every `test` completed.

How to make `publish` run only on release?

Comment: An option here would be to build the process another way: you could use a reusable workflow for the test process, then your publish workflow would just be triggered by the release, but be composed of 2 jobs. The first one to perform the test using the reusable workflow, that would be mandatory for the second job execution, that would print the message depending on the first job conclusion status.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your solution is that [using multiple events causes each event to trigger its own workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-multiple-events). So the workflow run has no way of referencing both the "test complete" and the "on release" conditions separately. Currently there is no way of doing this in GitHub Actions.

The easiest option would be to make your testing workflow run on every push to main and on release, and add a final job that will run if a release triggered the workflow. So you would append this to your test workflow:

```yaml
  on-test-success-and-release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.release.target_commitish == 'main'
    steps:
      - run: echo 'The test job passed and a release triggered this workflow'
```

This will have the downside of the testing job being repeated whenever a release is created, but this is negligible as long as your releases are not too frequent.